# Verification of authenticity of an object turn to be true even if it is outside the range of a scale estimated error boundary. It is like a puzzle!

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, error-analysis

I am reading a book and it makes the following question:

"A friend asks to
borrow your precious diamond for a day to show her family. You are a bit
worried, so you carefully have your diamond weighed on a scale which reads
8.17 grams. The scale’s accuracy is claimed to be more or less 0.05 gram The next day you
weigh the returned diamond again, getting 8.09 grams. Is this your diamond?"

Afterwards He answers

"The scale readings are measurements and are not perfect. They
do not necessarily give the “true” value of the mass. Each measurement could
have been high or low by up to 0.05 gram or so. The actual mass of your
diamond lies most likely between 8.12 grams and 8.22 grams. The actual mass
of the returned diamond is most likely between 8.04 grams and 8.14 grams.
These two ranges overlap, so the data do not give you a strong reason to
doubt that the returned diamond is yours".

I am going to make a test very important in my country. And this test explore this types of questions a lot. Questions that are like "puzzles". So I want to be familiar with this types of problems. I don't see sense in the authors example. First I thought it was not his diamond because the "allowed" range of the original diamdond was 8.12 to 8.22. Afterwards a give it a little more thought and I thought "the original diamond could be 8.14, considering the scale error range, and the returned 8.14, considering the scale range. But afterwards I thought "but it makes no sense that it is his diamonds because if the original diamond range could be 8.12 to 8.22 the **other day it could not change this range** .

The question in the book:

[image: Douglas C. Giancoli - Physics principles with application]

For me it stays like this "The returned diamond is a new one with its especific range". If you think the scale is allowed to "renew" its value in each measument, it does make sense. It is trick. Do you think that the author used a wrong example too? If not, why?

Comment: This is an extreme example of Bayesian analysis and shows how to apply the standard deviation (0.05 gram) to evaluate the "confidence interval" of each reading.